# Store filehandles in array

Tags: arrays, vba, file-handling, filehandle

I try to open all `*.xlsx` files in a specified folder and store the filehandles in an array.

My code looks like this

```
Dim Files() As Workbook
ReDim Files(Count)

File = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")
Count = 0

Do While File <> ""
    Set Files(Count) = Workbooks.Open(Path & File, , True)
    Count = Count + 1
    File = Dir()
Loop
```

The code seems to work, however, when I run it a second time (hitting the run button again), I get an error number 13.

Debugging the code I tracked the problem to the line

```
Set Files(Count) = Workbooks.Open(Path & File, , True)
```

As I am unexperienced with vba I guess I didn't do this the right way...

What would be a preferable way to store filehandles to all files in a specific folder in an array?

Comment: ... maybe the program just misses the workbooks to be closed... I added `Files(Count).Close()` which solved the problem.

Comment: but that way you miss the `Workbook` object reference just stored in `Files()`...

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a path separator

```
Set Files(Count) = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & File, , True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but `Path` already has the trailing backslash... :(

Comment: well I wouldn't say that since you're writing `File = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")`

Answer (score -1):

The code should be:

```
Dim Files() As Workbook
Dim Count As Integer
ReDim Files(Count)

File = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")
Count = 0

Do While File <> ""
    ReDim Preserve Files(Count)
    Set Files(Count) = Workbooks.Open(Path & File, , True)
    Count = Count + 1
    File = Dir()
Loop
```

You need to redim your array. Preserve keeps the existing data.

Comment: Your first Redim should be removed. Redimming every time is a lot of work for VB.

Comment: thank you, but the array size is not the problem (I store the number of files in the folder to `Count` before I state `ReDim Files(Count)`). I tried your code but still get a RuntimeError 13. I really think I have a mistake in Workbooks.Open...

Comment: _"(I store the number of files in the folder to Count before I state ReDim Files(Count))."_ ->  So what's that `Count = Count + 1`for?

Comment: It's there to raise the index of `Files`